# What is the word for an applied template?

Tags: single-word-requests, computing

The notion of a template is that it is abstract and can be applied to future instances. Is there a word that means an instantiated template?

I'd prefer something that specifically refers to the fact that it came from a template, so not "instance".

Comment: *"templated instance"*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's actually what I'm using right now, but it's a mouthful and was hoping for something shorter.

Comment: I don't really see why you can't just use *instance* or *instantiation* in most contexts, since presumably in most cases where the fact of it coming from a template is relevant, that will already be implicit.

Comment: Why is the fact that it came from a template relevant? Is the created-from-template nature evident in the final result (and if so, is the intent to point that out)? Why not just call it whatever you'd have called it otherwise?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No it's not necessarily immediately evident. I'm a programmer and am using it for a member variable name and thus need that name to convey as accurately as possible what information it is representing.

Comment: -1 shows no research effort. Also, voting to close General Reference: the link to Stroustrup's glossary is more than sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: You show no research effort.

Comment: I believe the most accurate word for this is "iteration."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Stroustrup](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/glossary.html#Gspecialization):

> **specialization** : a class or function generated from a template by supplying a complete set of template arguments

So a templated sorting function, for example, can be said to be **specialized** for `double`, or what have you.

Template *[instantiation](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/glossary.html#Gtemplate-instantiation)* is the process of creating a specialization from a template.

Comment: Referring specifically to the C++ use of the term, but still very fitting to know what term they use. Thanks!