# A word for that which is created from a template?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the word for an applied template?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58883/what-is-the-word-for-an-applied-template)

I am looking for a word to describe that which is created from a template.

I am writing software which is used for testing. I created an object which can be used as a template for actual tests. These 'implementations' (as I have called them) just pass a few parameters to the template and the template is executed. It is important to recognise an implementation as such and to be able to refer back to the template as this is where the actual actions are performed.

I am not happy with the word 'implementation' as I find it too general. Is there a better word I could use? Bear in mind that the end user has to create (implement?) the template itself before template-implementations can be created. It gets a bit confusing. I had thought of 'wrapper' but this doesn't fit well with 'template' - perhaps 'template' is the wrong term ;-)

**CLARIFICATION** I need a term which the end-users will understand (i.e. non-IT people).

P.S. I am aware of this question [What is the word for an applied template?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58883/what-is-the-word-for-an-applied-template). The fact that I'm asking virtually the same question shows that the question should not have been closed!

Comment: In software especially- a template is instantiated and the result is an *instantiation*.  It is also sometimes called an  *instance* of the template.

Comment: @Jim - thanks. In my code I would use those terms but I need a word which 'normal' people will understand ;-)

Comment: My advice is to educate your reader and then use the correct term.  Template instance seems like reasonable wording for normal people.

Comment: 'Instance' works, although it tends to have a more specific meaning ie. an object created according to a class definition. 'Copy' is a more general word eg. in biology where a DNA template results in 'copies'.

Comment: @Pete855217- But *copy* implies sameness- a template takes parameters which can vary between instantiations so the resulting instances are not the same at all.

Comment: What about 'derivative'? Wikipedia: "a modification of an original work"

Comment: There is always [this](http://www.xkcd.com/1133/) approach.-  "The thing you get when you make one using the directions you've written"

Comment: @Jim lol - Good job our screens are bigger nowadays - that kind of naming would never fit on 3270 teminal display!

Comment: I think you should ask this question on http://stackoverflow.com tagging you question as Software Development. This has more to do with Software Development than the English language.

Comment: It is true that I am writing software but I am looking for a term to communicate an idea to a non-IT person. That is why I posed the question here. I really *don't* want an IT answer.

Comment: @paul I still think IT people can help you arrive at a good non-IT term.

Comment: I would say "iteration" is almost exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I would call it a "realization," in the sense that the template is something abstract, and the object produced is now something real.

Answer (score 1):

A template is used to create a final product. The name of that final product will vary according to what it is. A carpenter might use a template to produce a moulding. Some very well-known office software uses templates to produce documents, spreadsheets and presentations; this is the usage that most non-IT-savvy people will be reasonably familiar with.

There’s nothing wrong with using the simplest, most direct expressions.

It appears that what is happening is that your users *put together* or *assemble* the template (from, say, *widgets*) and then *use* that template to create a *test script*.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something as simple as "copy"?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call one "the first template" or "the setup template" and the other "the second template." That would seem to take a lot less brain power to parse, for non-geeks, than talking about objects and implementations.

Answer (score 1):

A **Prototype** can be seen as an "applied template".  Many people will know the word 'prototypical'.

The Ruby community has some board use of the term for these things being "Fabrications" ([based on this gem](http://www.fabricationgem.org/)).  Maybe a 'fabricator' for the common audience.

In OOP, a "[Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)" is a common pattern-object, that creates other objects in its nature.  A 'factory' is also a word that can be used with broad audiences, since most-everyone will know something about factories.